# How to clean up .repo directory after syncing?

Tags: android, ubuntu, cyanogenmod, repo

I was recently working on Android development and had to sync the Cyanogenmod 12.1 sources to my computer using repo.
Due to some connectivity issue, I had a frequently disconnecting internet connection which led to a failing repo sync several times.
repo only downloads the packages which were previously not downloaded but re-downloads a packages if it was interrupted.

I checked and found that i had several tmp files in the .repo/projects/*/   folders which was the junk leftover from the failed syncs.
How do i delete those to free up some space, while also not disrupting my local repository. I cannot manually remove those since i have 182 projects in my repository.

Mods: Please advice if Stack Overflow is not the right place for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick search of repo source code, It seems the tmp files will be removed after a successful *repo sync*. So, don't bother with it, it will disappear after you got a good internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll be able to confirm that only after I complete the sync.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cd android/system

$ find .repo | grep tmp_  | xargs rm -f
```

this will remove all the stale tmp_* files